# Browser local storage get and set json objects issue

Tags: jquery, json

Im receiving from a webservice an string which has a json format. Using `jQuery.parseJSON` im creating a JSON object on client side (and i can access it without issues).

After i use `localStorage.setItem` to add my JSON object to browser local storage. My issue comes when i do a `localStorage.getItem` and i get an `[object object]` and i dont know how to access my object like a JSON object anymore.

Do you know whats the cause and any solution for this?

Thanks

Jose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stringify your object before storing it, and later parse it when you retrieve it:

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

//retrieve the object and parse it again
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, you need to parse the JSON that is returned from `localStorage.getItem()`and then you can use it as you use the class object. `localStorage.getItem()` retuns a JSON object and you will again have to parse it so as to use it. You can check in Firebug that it is the same json.Hope this helps..